# Format potentially invalid XML

Tags: c#, xml

I'm working on an application that allows users edit/fix XML.
A part of this is to format the XML for better readability.

As the XML might be invalid, the existing methods I found for formatting (like `XmlWriter` or `XDocument`) don't work for me.
There might be all sorts of problems with the XML, although the most common is unescaped special characters.

```
public static string FormatXml(string xml)
{
    var tags = xml
        .Split('<')
        .Select(tag => tag.TrimEnd().EndsWith(">") ? tag.TrimEnd() : tag); //Trim whitespace between tags, but not at the end of values

    var previousTag = tags.First(); //Preserve content before the first tag, e.g. if the initial < is missing
    var formattedXml = new StringBuilder(previousTag);
    var indention = 0;
    
    foreach (var tag in tags.Skip(1))
    {
        if (previousTag.EndsWith(">"))
        {
            formattedXml.AppendLine();
            if (tag.StartsWith("/"))
            {
                indention = Math.Max(indention - 1, 0);
                formattedXml.Append(new string('\t', indention));
            }
            else
            {
                formattedXml.Append(new string('\t', indention));
                if (!tag.EndsWith("/>"))
                {
                    indention++;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            indention = Math.Max(indention - 1, 0);
        }

        formattedXml.Append("<");
        formattedXml.Append(tag);
        previousTag = tag;
    }

    return formattedXml.ToString();
}
```

Sofar the method produces reasonable output for all cases I came up with.

I'm mostly worried that I missed some special cases of valid XML that would get messed up.

Comment: Is the `xml` passed to the method before or after the user edit the xml?

Comment: @Heslacher: The method is invoked by the user through a 'Format XML' button.

Answer (score 5):

There's a test suite of 2000 test cases available at https://www.w3.org/XML/Test/ - try it out.

From a quick glance, it's not clear to me how you're handling content within comments or CDATA sections - which might be well-formed XML, or it might be something approximating to well-formed XML.

Another comment is that messing with whitespace is dangerous in mixed content. With inline markup (bold, italic etc) preserving whitespace as written may be important.

Comment: +1 I have a look a the test cases. Mixed content might be problematic. In my specific use case it's not a concern, but generally my code would need some major cases to handle this.